# MySQL database: Foreign key error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I am trying to create a table which follows as:

```
CREATE TABLE gives (
pid VARCHAR(7),
crn VARCHAR(7),
PRIMARY KEY (pid, crn),
FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES professor(pid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (crn) REFERENCES course(crn) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

crn comes form course table which is:

```
CREATE TABLE course(
crn VARCHAR(7),
.........
PRIMARY KEY(crn, .....)
.........
)
```

pid comes from professor table which is:

```
CREATE TABLE professor(
pusername VARCHAR(20),
pid VARCHAR(7),
........
PRIMARY KEY(pusername, pid....),
FOREING KEY(pusername) REFERENCES b_user(username) ON DELETE CASCADE,
........
)
```

b_user follows as

```
CREATE TABLE b_user (
username VARCHAR(20),
........
PRIMARY KEY(username, .....)
........
)
```

However this 'gives' table gives me an error:

> ## 1005 - Can't create table `courseweb`.`gives` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I have created types of gives before, never got an error. Only difference is this time I used those 'ON DELETE CASCADE's which gives a chance for chain deletion when I delete a user from b_user.

I have no idea why this is happening, I think my syntax is correct.

Comment: I'm not `MySQL`, but I know in `SQL Server` a Foreign Key can't reference part of a Primary Key. This might be the case here.

Comment: What is table courseweb?

Comment: Also, now is a good time to make sure your professor table is spelt correctly :)

Comment: Ah, that might be it - the FK references professor, but your table is incorrectly spelt proffesor?

Comment: The way the primary key for table `course` is defined implies that column `pid` only partly defines the primary key. Likewise, column `crn` only partly defines the primary key for table `course`. So my question is this: If table `gives` presumably describes what professor gives what course, how can columns `pid` and `crn` fully specify a professor and course respectively?

Comment: I meant to say: The way the primary key for table `professor` is defined implies that column `pid` only partly defines the primary key. Likewise, column `crn` only partly defines the primary key for table `course`. So my question is this: If table `gives` presumably describes what professor gives what course, how can columns `pid` and `crn` fully specify a professor and course respectively? If `course`.'crn` and `professor`.`pid` are sufficient candidate keys, then try just defining these columns as the primary keys.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson MySQL does not require foreign keys to refer to unique/primary keys (even if there is rarely  a need for fk's that reference non-identifying data).

Answer (score 3):

From the official docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any column or group of
>   columns. However, **in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.**

In other words, to have any reference/fk to `professor.pid`, `professor` must contain an index starting with `pid`.

Comment: I alrealdy have index starting with pid

Comment: Not in `professor` according to what you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

Your FK references table professor, but you've incorrectly spelt the table as proffesor

Comment: Its a typo, i didnt copy and pasted it. I wrote this by my hand only first create table is a copy-paste

Comment: I would expect if the original error was a typo it would have come up with a different error, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your table :

```
 CREATE TABLE gives (
    pid VARCHAR(7),
    crn VARCHAR(7),
    PRIMARY KEY (pid, crn))
```

Then add the constraints :

```
ALTER TABLE `gives`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `pid_c` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `professor` (`pid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `crn_c` FOREIGN KEY (`crn`) REFERENCES `course` (`crn`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: I could create the gives table, obviously,  but the error is still the same after ALTER TABLE

Comment: Check the InnoDB table status by using this command. SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

This will enlighten you on what you are doing wrong.